# Getting ContentType from Word Add-in

Tags: vsto

Anyone know how to use "Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument" in VSTO to get the document content type?

Example something like below,
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"